# Submit a form by code

Tags: php, form-submit

I am trying to programmatically submit a form but get an error that says: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'submit': object is null or undefined 
verify1.php, line 9 character 5

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.getElementById("repeatForm").submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php  
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');  
  $privatekey = "6Ld1N9ISAAAAAB_lXt0Es0muh2cfikSgVrUP4ZXh";  
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],                                
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);  
if (!$resp->is_valid) {    
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly    
echo '<script language="JavaScript">submitform();</script>'; 
; 
/*echo "<script>window.location.href = 'Information-Request-Voodoo-Websites.php';</script>";*/
        } else {
        echo "<script>window.location.href = 'Confirm-Information-Request.html';</script>";   
        // Your code here to handle a successful verification  
        }  ?>

        <?php
if (isset($_POST['name2'])) $_SESSION['name2'] =$_POST['name2'];
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) $_SESSION['phone'] =$_POST['phone'];
if (isset($_POST['email'])) $_SESSION['email'] =$_POST['email'];
if (isset($_POST['company'])) $_SESSION['company'] =$_POST['company'];
if (isset($_POST['pages'])) $_SESSION['pages'] =$_POST['pages'];
if (isset($_POST['shopping'])) $_SESSION['shopping'] =$_POST['shopping'];
if (isset($_POST['new'])) $_SESSION['new'] =$_POST['new'];
if (isset($_POST['general'])) $_SESSION['general'] =$_POST['general'];
if (isset($_POST['respond'])) $_SESSION['respond'] =$_POST['respond'];
?>

          <form id="repeatForm" action="Information-Request-Voodoo-Websites.php" method="post">


    <span name="sprytextfield1">
      <label for="name2">Please enter your name:</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="name2" value="<?php echo((isset($_POST["name"]))?$_POST["name"]:"") ?>" size="30" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield2">
      <label for="phone">Please enter your phone number:</label>
      <input name="phone" type="text" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="phone" value="<?php echo((isset($_POST["phone"]))?$_POST["phone"]:"") ?>" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield3">
      <label for="email">Please enter your email address:</label>
      <input name="email" type="text" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="email" value="<?php echo((isset($_POST["email"]))?$_POST["email"]:"") ?>" size="40" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextarea1">
      <label for="company">Enter a brief description of your company:</label>
      <br />
      <textarea name="company" cols="65" rows="3" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="company"><?php echo((isset($_POST["company"]))?$_POST["company"]:"") ?></textarea>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></p>
    <p>Anticipated number of pages:<span id="sprytextfield4">
    <label for="pages"></label>
    <input name="pages" type="text" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="pages" value="<?php echo((isset($_POST["pages"]))?$_POST["pages"]:"") ?>" size="7" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span><span id="spryselect1">
        <label for="shopping">Shopping cart required?</label>
        <select name="shopping" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="shopping">
          <option value="yes">yes</option>
          <option value="no">no</option>
        </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></p>
    <p><span id="spryselect2">
      <label for="new">Does this work concern a new or existing web site?</label>
      <select name="new" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="new">
        <option value="existing" <?php if (!(strcmp("existing", ((isset($_POST["new"]))?$_POST["new"]:"")))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>existing</option>
        <option value="new" <?php if (!(strcmp("new", ((isset($_POST["new"]))?$_POST["new"]:"")))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>new</option>
        </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextarea2">
      <label for="general">Add any additiional comments here or ask questions. </label>
      <textarea name="general" cols="65" rows="4" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="general"><?php echo((isset($_POST["general"]))?$_POST["general"]:"") ?></textarea>
</span></p>
    <p><span id="spryselect3">
      <label for="respond">How would you like us to respond?</label>
      <select name="respond" class="inputTextBoxFormat" id="respond">
        <option value="email" <?php if (!(strcmp("email", ((isset($_POST["respond"]))?$_POST["respond"]:"")))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>email</option>
        <option value="phone" <?php if (!(strcmp("phone", ((isset($_POST["respond"]))?$_POST["respond"]:"")))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>phone</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are trying to submit your form before it is loaded.

Simply push your submit line lower or execute it in the onload event of the body tag.

```
<?php
if(!$resp->is_valid) {
    $submit=' onload="submitform()"';
} else {
    $submit="";
}
?>
<body<?php echo($submit); ?>>
```

Comment: rekire thanks for your help - you nailed it! I moved the submit to bel;ow the form and now all works. Da! Thanks again!